# How to ADD days to selected date in asp using ajax calendar extendar?

Tags: c#, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to add or subtract dates in C# using ajax calendar extender?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13006280/how-to-add-or-subtract-dates-in-c-sharp-using-ajax-calendar-extender)

I have two textboxes in which i have used ajax calendar extender. When I choose a date from one textbox, I want the other one filled with a date calculated from the one selected by adding some days or months. How can i do that?

Comment: You must not duplicate your questions: here you ask for something and wait for others to reply! If you are in a hurry, call someone and pay for this!! Anyway, you're new here, so you should learn. Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: ok sorry next time i will follow the rules and regulation.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
DateTime? SelDate = myCalendarExtender.SelectedDate;

if (SelDate != null)
{
    DateTime SelectedDate = SelDate .Value;
}

DateTime Selected_Date= SelectedDate ;

DateTime result= Selected_Date.AddDays(30);
```

Comment: i dont want to add in todays date. i want to add in date which i have selected in first text box.

Comment: pass the date selected as value of SelectedDate...Simple...

Comment: it only adds in system date not in mine date.

Comment: please tell me that i am very beggginer cant understand.

Comment: have you replaced the DateTime.Now with the selected value from calender control? Show us what you have tried.

Comment: DateTime SelectedDate = DateTime.Now; 
            DateTime result = SelectedDate.AddDays(30);
            TextBox6.Text = result.ToString();
this is what i have done!

Comment: replace the first line with DateTime SelectedDate= calendercontrolname.SelectedDate. i have not tried it just a guess .

Comment: how can i select my date which i have inserted ?? there is no of selectedDate after datetime..

Comment: ERROR!
Error 2 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.DateTime?' to 'System.DateTime'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729553/system-datetime-vs-system-datetime

Comment: Umair: You have a `nullable` variable that you are trying to cast to a `System.DateTime`.  Cast it to a `System.DateTime` e.g. `(DateTime)calender.SelectedDate;`

Comment: @UmairJaved try google before you post each error

Comment: again an EXCEPTION raised " Invalid Operation exception was unhandled by user code".

Comment: DateTime SelectedDate = (DateTime)CalendarExtender1.SelectedDate; 
            DateTime result = SelectedDate.AddDays(2);
            TextBox6.Text = result.ToShortDateString();

Comment: Nullable object must have a value.. again this is the reason!! :(

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want the date on the second `TextBox` to change after the user has selected a calendar date on the first `TextBox`.  You need to intercept the `OnClientDateSelectionChanged` event (on the client) (in javascript) and write a handler (in javascript) that will update the value on the second `TextBox` from the value selected on the first

Basically given this:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tbFirst" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="tbSecond" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<cc1:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender7" 
runat="server" OnClientDateSelectionChanged="DateSelected" TargetControlID="tbFirst" />
```

Then in a javascript block you:

```
function DateSelected(sender,args)
{
     alert('You have selected : ' + sender._selectedDate);
     //TODO: Select the second box and set it's value to whatever is needed 

}
```